# Set ASP Literal text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, literals

I have an asp:Literal on my page (**which cannot be converted to a Label or any other control**) that I need to change the text of via JavaScript. I have the following code that works for a *Label*. Can anybody help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeText() {
            document.getElementById('<%= Test.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'New Text';
        }
    </script>

        <a href="#" onclick='changeText()'>Change Text</a>
        <asp:Label id="Test" runat="server" Text="Original Text" />
```

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**
I cannot change from a literal as the code behind writes HTML/CSS to it for an Information Message e.g:

```
LITMessage.Text = "<div class='success'>Information Successfully Updated</div>"
```

Comment: Why can't you change it to any other control? This sounds really strange paired with the requirement to change the text.

Comment: @Stilgar - I have updated my original question

Comment: Your update as to why you can't change to a label doesn't make sense. This is one of the specific purposes of the label control. Anything you can do with a literal you can pretty much do with a label just the same. That being said, I've +1 to @Slaks as his idea seems simplest to me.

Comment: Because technically, well at least for W3C compliance, you are not supposed to wrap a div inside a span - mainly as this may not render correctly in the future if IE/FF etc decide you cannot do this

Comment: You can just work with the div. Just give it an unique ID (make sure there are no multiple instances of the same string).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`<asp:Literal>` controls don't create their own HTML tag.
Therefore, there is no element that you can manipulate.

Instead, you can wrap the `<asp:Literal>` in a `<div>` tag with an ID.

Comment: ... or a `<span>` tag if it's just a little bit of text content.

Comment: Or use `<asp:Label>`, it is a Literal wrapped in a span.

Answer (score 8):

An ASP.NET Literal doesn't add any markup to the page. Therefore you have to wrap your content in some container so that you can edit it via JavaScript:

Assuming you had the following Literal on the page:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Id="literalControl" />
```

And were setting the text via code behind (because if you're not, you could just create the span/div in the markup to begin with and not have this issue):

```
literalControl.Text = "Some text you want to change";
```

The code behind becomes:

```
literalControl.Text = "<span id='myId'>Some text you want to change</span>";
```

And the JavaScript would be:

```
document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML = 'New Text';
```

Answer (score 5):

Does the literal contain html markup?

if not, you could wrap the literal control in a div and give it an id. Then use js to replace the text within that div.

in response to your update:

In that case, since you are rendering a div with a class of `success`, I would use jQuery to update the html in that div...it would be as simple as:

```
$('.success').html('new html goes here');
```

Comment: @james updated answer. if possible use jquery to udpdate the text in the div inside the literal

Comment: That is a good answer, but I do not wish to use jQuery (don't understand it!) However, I have rated it up for other people who understand jQ.

Comment: jQuery will make your life a lot easier in scenarios like this. I would recommend it to any web developer. There are a ton of great resources on the net including the jquery website. Among other things, jquery allows you to select elements on the page by css class or element id. You can than perfom various operations/manipulate those elements.

Comment: in my answer above...$(".success") would select the div with the class of `success` applied to it. calling the `.html` function would allow you to replace the html in the selected div

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the `<asp:literal>` control in a `<div>` and then use jQuery if needed to clear the contents like shown below:

```
<div id="divMyText">
  <asp:Literal ID="MyText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

Here is how to clear the text using jQuery:

```
//Clear the html inside of the div
$("#divMyText").html("");
```

Answer (score 1):

A Literal is a direct render of text to the page. The only HTML it will render will be the HTML markup you include in the text string you set to the Literal. Instead of using a Literal surrounded by a div (unless you specifically want that functionality) you can use an [ASP Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) and perform operations on it.