# I have an updated div, but my code-behind behave as it has never changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a div object (riddleIdHere), and js code that during the running inserts a number into this div. I want my C# code-behind to use this number, but the code-behind gives me an empty string like I have never inserted a number into this div.
Can anyone help me, please?

Here's my div:

```
<div id='riddleIdHere' runat='server' style='display:none'></div>
```

Js:

```
document.getElementById("riddleIdHere").innerText = riddleid;
```

*riddleid is a numeric variable

my code-behind is supposed to update a data table using my InnerText:

```
sql = "UPDATE YHRiddles " +
    "SET rateSum +='"+ b + "' " +
    "WHERE id = '" + riddleIdHere.InnerText + "';";
Debug.WriteLine(riddleIdHere.InnerText);
```

The Debug.WriteLine is here to see why it doesn't work, and it prints an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you change on page using javascript its not automatically send on code behind.

To do that you have to create an other hidden input control (that is the actually one that can send post back insformations on code behind) and also write there what information's you need to send on `value` not anywhere else. The Value is the only one that you can send.

The `InnerText` on code behind is to give some information on how to render your control - did not have interactivity with the final page.

Example : Page.aspx

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

        <script>
        function OpenIt()
        {
            document.getElementById("<%=riddleIdHere.ClientID%>").innerText = "some text";
            document.getElementById("<%=hfRiddleStatus.ClientID%>").value = "some text";
            form.s
        }
        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="riddleIdHere" runat="server" >Some Content</div>
            

            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hfRiddleStatus" Value="0" />

            
            <asp:Button runat="server" Id="btnRunMe" OnClick="btnRunMe_Click" OnClientClick="OpenIt();" Text="RunMe" />

            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtDebugInfos" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnRunMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDebugInfos.Text = hfRiddleStatus.Value;
}
```

What to expect - after the click the `hfRiddleStatus.Value` must contains the "some text" we put using javascript.

Comment: So what actually do you recommend me to do?

Comment: @hpr write at the same time some flags on an input control and post them back. when I find some time I will update with an example

Comment: I'll wait for your example, thanks!

Comment: Can you please add the example?

Comment: @hpr I have add a minimum example that I tested and working. I Hop that this gives you an idea to move on.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Literal:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="riddleIdHere" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
```

and then [set asp literal text with js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4946013/3085925).

Comment: Thanks, I did it but it doesn't work. I mean, still - the innerText HAS changed, but the code behind didn't recognize it.